# Non-zero idempotent element in a non-nilpotent left artinian ring

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $F$ be a field and $V$ be a non-nilpotent(i.e. $V^n\neq 0$ for any $n\geq 1$) associative algebra over F such that $dim_{F}(V)\lt +\infty$. Then there exists a non-zero idempotent element in $V$.

Consequently, I was wondering if there exists an non-zero idempotent element in $R$ where $R$ is a non-nilpotent left artinian ring.

First, for any minimal left Ideal $I$ of $R$, we have $I^2={0}$ or $I=Ie=Re$ for some non-zero idempotent element in $I$. Thus we can consider the jacobson radical $J(R)$ of R which is the largest nilpotent ideal in $R$. $R/J(R)$ is also a left artinian ring and it must have a non -zero idempotent element.

But I don't know how to continue this progress.

Comment: You are apparently working with rings without identity?  That is a hard pill to swallow for many, so you should be up-front about it.

Comment: I don't know how idempotent lifting works in rings without identity. If idempotents still lift, then a nonzero idempotent from $R/J(R)$ would lift to one in $R$.

Comment: @rschwieb Yes, the ring in here doesn't  necessarily have an identity.

Comment: @rschwieb  I just found a proof. However, it seems to work only in commutative ring.  https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00J9

Comment: you’ll have to be careful: their context is certainly assuming identity.   What part makes you think commutative the is necessary? It is very similar to the proof I have somewhere here (assuming identity) which works for noncommutative rings.

Comment: @rschwieb We can replace $I$ with $J(R)$. And Let $e'=3e^2-2e^3$. But in the last paragraph, $(e_1-e_2)^3=(e_1-e_2)$ doesn't work...

Comment: that is only proving uniqueness right? THat doesn’t really matter to you does it?

Comment: @rschwieb But the $e$  in this proof can be zero...The uniqueness doesn't matter

Comment: no, if $\bar e\notin I$ then of course it cannot lift to $e=0$.

Comment: @rschwieb Sorry, I don't express this  clealy...I mean $e'$ can be zero. So if we continue this progress. the last idempotent element $e$ might be zero...

Comment: No lift of $\bar e$ , in particular $e’$, can be zero as long as you started with $\bar e + I\nea 0+I$.  It’s the same reason s in my last comment.

Comment: @rschwieb Oh, I undertand it totally. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

[Steven Gaal's Linear Analysis..](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486478513) states in proposition I.7.11 that

> If $A$ is a ring with identity satisfying the minimum condition for left ideals then every non-nilpotent left ideal contains an idempotent element.

$A$ is not assumed commutative.

Proof proceeds as follows. Let $I_0$ is non-nilpotent ideal in $A$.

1. Find minimal non-nilpotent ideal $J\subset I_0$, then $J^2=J$.
2. Find minimal $I'\subset J$ such that $JI' \neq 0$, it is possible because $JJ\neq 0$
3. There is $x\in I'$, such that $J^2x = Jx \neq 0.$ Then $Jx = I'$. Then $ex=x, e\in J$, then $(e^2-e)x = 0$ and $e\ne 0$
4. $e^2-e\in I = (0:x)\cap J\subsetneq J,$ where $(0:x) = \{y\in A|yx=0\}$. $I\neq J,$ because $Jx\neq 0$. Hence $I$ is nilpotent. (Proof in the book proceeds as if $I = 0$)
5. (Not explained in the book) Lift $e^2-e = 0$ from $A/I$ to $A$ as in [Stacks-00J9](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00J9) using Newton's method. No need to assume commutativity, because $I^n = 0$ already for some $n$.

$J(A)$ can be equal to $A$ according to the book (theorem I.7.5) if there is no identity. And it looks like lifting from $A/J(A)$ to $A$ does not work in non-unital case.

PS. I came to this question while searching for clarifications for the proof.

UPD. Fixed 3d bullet. Still do not understand why identity is needed in the proof.

UPD1. One can omit reference to [Stacks-00J9](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00J9).

5. $(Je)^n \ne0, $ because $(Je)^nx \ni x\ne 0$. Then $Je = J$ and $e'e=e,$ where $e, e' \in J, $ both non-zero.
6. One can find $e$ with $Je=J, Je'=J, e'e=e$ and $(0:e)\cap J$ minimal.
7. $(0:e)\cap J = (0:e'e)\cap J \supset (0:e')\cap J$, then $e'^2 - e' \in (0:e)\cap J = (0:e')\cap J$
8. Finally $(e'^2 - e')e' = 0$, and $e'^4 - e'^2 = 0$